# Test Dome pipeline for ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm practicing on test dome and come across to this question I don't have idea how to use lambda but I still try so I don't know if I'm right. Here's the instruction:

> As part of a data processing pipeline, complete the implementation of the pipeline method:
>
> The method should accept a variable number of functions, and it should return a new function that accepts one parameter arg.
>
> The returned function should call the first function in the pipeline with the parameter arg, and call the second function with the result of the first function.
>
> The returned function should continue calling each function in the pipeline in order, following the same pattern, and return the value from the last function.
>
> For example, `pipeline(-> (x) { x * 3 }, -> (x) { x + 1 }, -> (x) { x / 2 })` then calling the returned function with `3` should return `5`.

And here's my code.

```
def pipeline(*funcs)
  -> (arg) {
    counter = 0
    temp = 0
    funcs.each do |func|
      if counter == 0
        temp += func.call(arg)
        counter += 1
      else
        temp = func.call(temp)
      end
    end
    return temp
  }
end

fun = pipeline(-> (x) { x * 3 }, -> (x) { x + 1 }, -> (x) { x / 2 })
puts (fun.call(3))
```

```
Output:

Run OK


5
```

but I got this error.

```
done Example case: Correct answer 
error  Various functions: TypeError: pipeline.rb:7:in `+' 
error  Various data types: TypeError: pipeline.rb:7:in `+'
```

if you're curious here is the question its free.

https://www.testdome.com/d/ruby-interview-questions/6

Here's the starting code:

```
def pipeline(*funcs)
  -> (arg) {
    # write your code here  
  }
end

fun = pipeline(-> (x) { x * 3 }, -> (x) { x + 1 }, -> (x) { x / 2 })
puts (fun.call(3)) # should print 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is simply reduce the array of functions.

```
def pipeline(*args)
  ->(x) { args.reduce(x) { |acc, f| f.(acc) } }
end
fun = pipeline(-> (x) { x * 3 }, -> (x) { x + 1 }, -> (x) { x / 2 })
#⇒ #<Proc:0x0000561a73f48768@(pry):36 (lambda)>
fun.(3)
#⇒ 5
```

Comment: Thank you! But still, I don't get how it works sorry. I have to study this part can you suggest some reference?

Comment: I am not sure. Reducing is a very common CS approach, covered everywhere including https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function) What happens there is actually we walk through the functions in the pipeline and subsequently apply them to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is way simpler, by assigning a variable to control the flow of the operations make it crash

try this:

```
funcs.each do |func|
 arg = func.call(arg)     
end
return arg
```